# fsockopen() from 127.0.0.1 is not working

Tags: php, smtp, email, fsockopen

I'm trying to connect to an SMTP server from my local machine (127.0.0.1).  I'm able to connect to other SMTP servers, but this one in particular will not connect from my local machine, it will connect however from 4 other remote servers I have tested on.

I receive the following error trying to connect from my local machine:

> Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to mail.domain.com:25 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )

Would anyone know what may cause the server to not allow connections from 127.0.0.1, It's not behind a firewall and postfix is accepting all networks.

Thank you!

Comment: Localhost is 127.0.0.*1* - but doesn't sound like that's relevant here, though. If you are connecting to other machines successfully you'll be making connections on a non-loopback interface.

Comment: Oops, thanks edited the post.  Same issues though.

Comment: I've tried doing through cmd prompt 'telnet mail.domain.com 25' but receive connection failed.  Yet again, the mail.domain.com works from a remote server.

Comment: is the ip address of mail.domain.com reachable at all from the external ip address - not 127.0.0.1, this is just the loopback - but the interface of your local host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an ISP issue, which blocked port 25.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the SMTP server is not bound to the loop-back device. Check its configuration. You usually signal you want it to listen to all interfaces by specifying the address `0.0.0.0` (may be different for IPv6).

Comment: We have inet_interfaces = all in postfix config